# When to use exception or when to use message?

Tags: c#, exception

I am wondering what is the best way to warn about a data that a user has to provide is missing or wrong.

Exceptions, for me, are when there are something exceptional that I can't control, for example, if i try to write a file, there is no permissions or the hard drive is full. If I am querying database, the database is down or the LAN connections doesn't work... etc.

But if it is because a user doesn't provide a needed information or it is incorrect, this is something that I have control over it, so from some point of view, it is not an exception, because it depends on me. But if I don't use exceptions, to warn the user, I have to show a dialog, so the code it is much more complex if I have considerate all the possibilities.

For example, with exceptions I could have this code:

```
try
{
    if(esData1Correct() == false) throw new Exception("Data1 incorrect");
    if(esData2Correct() == false) throw new Exception("Data2 incorrect");
    if(esData3Correct() == false) throw new Exception("Data3 incorrect");

    // All is correct, I continue with the code.
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

However, if I want to use dialogs, the code that I should use, or the code that I think I would have to use is something like that:

```
if(esData1Correct() == false)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Data1 is incorrect.");
}
else if(esData2Correct() == false)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Data2 is incorrect.")
}
else if(esData3Correct() == false)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Data3 is incorrect.")
}
else
{
    // All is correct, so I can continue with my code.
}
```

So which code is more correct, to use exceptions or messages to warn the user the information is not correct? Are there another better options?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this not something that should have been on code review?
What is the exact problem you are facing that needs community support on SO?

Comment: In general, UI frameworks will provide an idiomatic way to validate user input.  The details will depend on the framework (WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET WebForme, ASP.NET MVC) and google will help you to find samples and tutorials.  Exceptions would be used if invalid input gets past the UI validation.  I must say don't understand why your question got 4 close votes as "primarily opinion based".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So which code is more correct, to use exceptions or messsages to warn
>   the user the information is not correct? Are there another better
>   options?

Neither is *more* correct and they both show the message to the user with or without the exceptions; mission accomplished. Indeed, you wouldn't warn the user with an exception per say so it's transparent to them anyway unless you plan to dump the stack trace to the UI (don't!!). There are things to consider when using exceptions and you certainly don't want to use them everywhere for everything but it's not *wrong* to use them for validation failures. Read on for more.

---

Exceptions *are* meant for exceptional conditions but what constitutes an exceptional condition varies. Linq's [`First`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=netframework-4.8), for example, will throw an exception if the `source` or `predicate` is null, the `source` is empty, or there's no element that matches the `predicate`. They could have just returned null but they chose to instead push the responsibility onto the caller to get it right. To me, that's a reasonable use of exceptions where it wasn't exactly necessary; a collection not containing an element that matches a predicate happens all the time so it's not exactly exceptional. And it's not uncommon to see `ArgumentException`s and `ArgumentNullException`s used in similar cases as yours; that's probably how I'd do it absent a more sophisticated approach.

But, first thing's first. I know this is an example but there are some pain-points that need to be addressed before worrying about which approach is more appropriate.

The following is objectively *stinky*:

```
try
{
    if(esData1Correct() == false) throw new Exception("Data1 incorrect");
    if(esData2Correct() == false) throw new Exception("Data2 incorrect");
    if(esData3Correct() == false) throw new Exception("Data3 incorrect");   

    //All is corerct, I continue with the code.
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Here, the code is using exceptions as *control flow*. You know something is wrong and can handle it at that point but instead throw and catch an exception to show the message; not good.

Also, don't throw or catch `System.Exception`. Exceptions, if used, should be specific enough to do something meaningful about it based on the context. Again, it's a small example but this sort of thing is everywhere in naive code.

Having said that, the first example would change and would not catch the `ArgumentException` if thrown. Let the caller catch the errors as they're the ones creating the exceptional condition; in other words, pull the validation out. The caller should also worry about what to do about it. As it is now, the validation code is tightly coupled to a message box which makes it difficult to reuse.

```
public Foo Bar(...)
{
    // A better way may be to validate them all and return a message
    // that aggregates all incorrect data back...
    if(!esData1Correct()) throw new ArgumentException("Data1 incorrect");
    if(!esData2Correct()) throw new ArgumentException("Data2 incorrect");
    if(!esData3Correct()) throw new ArgumentException("Data3 incorrect");
    // more ?
}
```

Given we're willing to remove the coupling to the message box, the second example doesn't really do what we want so instead create a `ValidationResult` class that can help you build a meaningful message to the user.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer second option, since it uses less resources, and is less complex.
Exception throwing should be used when you want to delegate exception handling to client-module which triggers your code and thus knows more about context in which your code is executed. There is not much sense in handling exception inside same method which throws it. You are right about that - in this example you know everything about what went wrong, and there is no need for exceptions, you just detect error and notify user about it, and that's all.

Answer (score 1):

The rule is generally: **Exceptions should be exceptional**.

A few examples:

```
var username = input.Text;
if (string.IsEmptyOrNull())
{
    // Give the user a chance to correct the input, this should not be an exception!
}
```

However, in an API, you might have a method that accepts a user object parameter:

```
var user = db.usernames.where(x => x.Id == user.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

If the input is supposedly already validated, but suddenly can't be found this is an exception. Something really weird happened! But if your query is an attempt to validate it should be treated as a valid query with no results:

```
var user = db.usernames.Where(x => x.username == user.username).FirstOrDefault();
if (user == null)
{
    // return useful error, this is not an exception
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends, mostly you handle the common conditions that are likely to happen (such as database connection in your example) by using simple `if` statement. Other situations that might occur and you think your code won't cover all of them, use `Exceptions`, this way you ensure that you catch the error trace.

Some other cases might need both `if` and `Exception`.

example :

```
try
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(someString))
    {
        someClass.Run(someString);
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // Log exception 
}
```

as the example above (sorry couldn't think of a real-world case). We used `try/catch` to catch any unhandled errors, while in the same time, we already validating some known conditions in the try block.

So, it depends on which part you're dealing with in your code. But in all cases, you're supposed to try handling all other errors. You have always to keep avoiding exceptions in your code as much as possible.

You're the judge on your code, choose whatever you see fits best your code.

Here is A good reference for [Best practices for exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions)